# Live Conditional Background Change

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm making an ATM app as a school project, essentially, the background color for the checking and savings account change depending on the current balance. The issue is that although it changes to red (since the accounts default as 0), it doesn't change to yellow (at $50) or green (at $100)

currentBalance is global, as to retain data. It pulls that variable from there. "ID" is specific for either checking or savings account. I can confirm that the color change works, since it changes from green (its default) to red, but it doesn't change once live updates start happening to the balance.

```js
var currentBalance = 0

function depositMoney(id) {
  // Select deposit button and add functionality
  document.querySelector(`${id} .deposit`).addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    // Prevent refresh page default
    event.preventDefault()
    // Obtain data from input box
    let deposited = document.querySelector(`${id} .input`).value
    // Turn data (currently string) into a number
    let intDeposited = parseInt(deposited)
    // Add number to current balance
    currentBalance += intDeposited
    // Select balance div which is where the balance will be shown
    let balanceNumber = document.querySelector(`${id} .balance`)
    // Show changed balance by modifying innerHTML and turning current balance into a string
    balanceNumber.innerHTML = "$" + currentBalance.toString();
  })
}

function backgroundColorBalance(id) {
  let accountColor = document.querySelector(`${id}`)
  if (currentBalance <= 25 && currentBalance >= 0) {
    accountColor.style.backgroundColor = "red"
  }
  if (currentBalance <= 50 && currentBalance > 25) {
    accountColor.style.backgroundColor = "yellow"
  }
  if (currentBalance > 50) {
    accountColor.style.backgroundColor = "green"
  }
}

// Invoke depositMoney() function for checking account
depositMoney("#checking")
// Invoke backgroundColorBalance() function for checking account
backgroundColorBalance("#checking")
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div><img src="ga.png" /></div>
  <div class="title">Bank of GA</div>
</div>

<div id="checking" class="account">
  <h2>Checking</h2>
  <div class="balance">$0</div>
  <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="enter an amount" />
  <input class="deposit" type="button" value="Deposit" />
  <input class="withdraw" type="button" value="Withdraw" />
</div>

<div id="savings" class="account">
  <h2>Savings</h2>
  <div class="balance">$0</div>
  <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="enter an amount" />
  <input class="deposit" type="button" value="Deposit" />
  <input class="withdraw" type="button" value="Withdraw" />
</div>
```

Comment: Got it! Added html source and deposit function which mutates currentBalance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset the background color after account balance changes are made. So add the following as the last line in your event listener code.

```
backgroundColorBalance(`${id}`);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't think about that